# Firefox installed with Flatpak, cannot open links from Thunderbrid

Tags: firefox

I recently switched to a Flatpak install of Firefox. I ten realised that I cannot open links from Thunderbird embedded in an e-mail.

Clicking on the link, I get he message "Keine Anwendung verfügbar" (in Eng,ish maybe "No app available"). I then found out that ist must have to do something with the fact that Firefox is not the default browser anymore. But youz cannot change this in "Settings". I gather or maybe it has to do something with the xdg-setting, but the tip "xdg-settings check default-web-browser <your_flatpak_browser.desktop>" also did not help.
What can I co to make downloads from an e-mail possible? I would not like to deinstall Flatplak....
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the Flatpak version of Firefox as the default browser in "Settings - Preferences". Then, clicking URL's in Thunderbird should open Firefox.

Comment: Thank you, but this is exactly the problem: Going to Settings - Preferences, they respective part is greyed out, I cannot do anything - and it says that Firefox is NOT my default browser. The button beside that with which I usually can make it the default browser does not react. On the very top it says that "Browser is administered by your organisation." (And I do not know what this means).

Comment: Strange. I have Chromium installed as a flatpak, and I can select it in that dialog, so the issue should not be with flatpak. Do not worry about "Browser is administered by your organisation.": this is normal, something different and not related to the problem. You may want to include this information in your question.

Comment: I also think that it is not a Flatpak problem, but it is annoying whenever I click on a link in an e-mail body I get this message. Thinking about to return to the classic PPA version if I do not get a solution. Do not understand that others do not have this problem...